# Apt-get update failing

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates

Hello I am new to ubuntu. I am running 14.04 Trusy. I have tried to search around but the solutions I have found has not helped. I get some errors when running apt-get update:

```
Hit http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de trusty Release        
Hit http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de trusty/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de trusty/multiverse Sources
Fetched 743 kB in 2s (368 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror-eu.packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-aarch64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I therefore found that you should look in the sources.list file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160217.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty universe
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security universe
deb http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.rz.tu-bs.de/pub/mirror/ubuntu-packages/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
# respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
```

**Extra**

I searched around on the name aarch64, which refers to arm. This I do not understand since my install should [from this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/), specifically AMD64. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: What does command `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` output?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala i386 and aarch64, which seems odd when I installed the other version. Does this mean it should be reinstalled with another package?

Comment: It might be possible to remove `aarch64` with command `dpkg --remove-architecture aarch64`

Comment: check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder as well. Repo information is read from the config files in this folder as well. One of the files may have this url listed. change binary-aarch64  binary-amd64 will hopefully work.

Comment: using dpkg --get-selections | grep aarch64 | awk '{print $1}' showed me why I have them all installed. I installed jetpack from nvidia to install a board called Nvidia jetson tx1. I am investigating some stuff :)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala the same errors are occurring when though I uninstalled the, :/

Comment: @Sreevisakh going through the folder made it possible to remove `ppa.launchpad` but nothing else.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala it helped deleting them just had to do some more commands to delete it. THX

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my host PC (Ubuntu 14.04 X86_64), after installing Jetpack 2.2 and flashing a Jetson TX1 with 64 bit userspace architecture. I was able to temporary get around the problem by doing this on my sources.list and source.list.d/ files. For example, for mongodb. I added [arch=amd64] before the url, after deb.

`deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse`, 
instead of `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse`

I am not sure if this is an issue with Nvidia's Jetpack or not. Anyone have a better solution?